# Angular.js resource rest call error TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I want to do a REST call to update data, i have done a GET request to fill up the form, and when i click on update button, i want to send and PUT call instead i get the Type error.

Here is the code:

//service.js

```
someservice.factory('update', function($resource) {
return $resource(connectionString + 'update', {}, {
put: {
  method: "PUT",
  isArray:
    'Content- false,
    headers: {Type': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sessionId': gv.sessionId
     }
    }
  })
})
```

//companyCtrl.js i have included update factory in controller dependencies

```
$scope.btnUpdate = function() {
    console.log("asd");
    update.put({}, {
       'data': $scope.data
    }, function(data){
       if(data.success){
          console.log("success");
       }
       else{
          console.log("faliure");
       }
    })
}
```

In my view i have button with ng-click="btnUpdate()"

console.log logs "asd" so everything is connected.

One thing that might have to do something with the problem, i'm using ui-router and i include controller within my state config like this:

```
  .state('admin.company', {
  url: "/company/{_id}",
  templateUrl: "./views/partials/company.html",
  controller: "companyCtrl"
```

The error stack is as follows:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Scope.$scope.btnUpdate (http://localhost:3000/dist/js/app.min.js:1:6680)
at http://localhost:3000/libs/angular/angular.js:10836:21
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with factory dependencies, i deleted one dependency and now everything works.

Answer (score -1):

Is that the entirety of companyCtrl.js? You haven't actually defined a function with name "companyCtrl" or registered it as a controller in the app. If you change companyCtrl.js to the following, that should fix it.

```
function companyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.btnUpdate = function() {
    console.log("asd");
    update.put({}, {
       'data': $scope.data
    }, function(data){
       if(data.success){
          console.log("success");
       }
       else{
          console.log("faliure");
       }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: no this is just a part of course, i have defined a function, and set the dependencies etc.